# "Edit with existing Vim" - how does it work?

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, multiple-files

I have Vim 8.1.1 on Windows 7.

I can click on the file with right mouse button, and there will be an option "Edit with Vim". Then, if I click another file, there will be two options: "Edit with Vim" and "Edit with existing Vim".

As I understand, the second option should open the file as a new buffer of the existing Vim. But actually it simply does nothing.

What I'm doing wrong?

(To open multiple files as different buffers, the following way works fine:

- Select multiple files,
- click on them,
- and select "Edit with single Vim".

However, I'm wondering why "Edit with existing Vim" doesn't work as I expected.)

Comment: There's some info in the wiki: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Launch_files_in_new_tabs_under_Windows It seems to be something to do with the registry. Using the SendTo method works.

Comment: It seems the link doesn't cover the described case

Comment: It's the registry changes that provide those links in the context menu.